# Difference between handleRequestInternal and handleRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have just started spring, I found that somewhere we are using `handlerequest()` method in controller and somewhere we are using `handlerequestinternal()` method.

I have tried google-ing this, but did not find any specific point.

Can any one explain what is the difference between these two functions and when we should implement each of them?

As I know spring framework will call by default `handlerequest()` function, so we can put our service layer there itself.

I am sure `handlerequestinternal()` must be providing some extra feature, but not sure.

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `handleRequest` and `handleRequestInternal` are used by the old Spring 2.0 controller framework.

`handleRequestInternal` is used when you're extending one of the pre-supplied base support classes (e.g. `AbstractController`, `SimpleFormController`, etc). These use the Template design pattern, and you supply your business logic in that method.

`handleRequest` is the method specified on the `Controller` interface itself. If you directly implement that interface, rather than extending one of the above base classes, then you need to implement `handleRequest` directly.

Both are obsolete, and not used in controllers written for Spring 2.5 and later.

Comment: So what to use instead in spring 4.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    this.checkAndPrepare(request, response, this instanceof LastModified);
    if (this.synchronizeOnSession) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            Object mutex = WebUtils.getSessionMutex(session);
            synchronized(mutex) {
                return this.handleRequestInternal(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    return this.handleRequestInternal(request, response);
}

protected abstract ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest var1, HttpServletResponse var2) throws Exception;
```

}

if in controller template classes like AbstractController and ParameterizableViewConterollers in this it will the child classes of Controller interface so spring peoples internally override the handleRequest method and call the abstract handleRequestInternal method so whenever we are using template classes we use this method otherwise we use the handleRequest() method only this the difference i think!.